# Waiting BackgoundWorker.DoWork() to finish

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio

In our .NET Framework based application we save a huge file using a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) to keep UI responsive. When we close it, we don't want to stop the work in background (default behavior) and truncate the file.

Does a more elegant way to wait for its completion exist compared to this one?

```
while (this.backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
{
    // Keep UI messages moving, so the form remains 
    // responsive during the asynchronous operation.
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Basically, what we are trying to achieve, is to see the application to disappear and continue to see a process alive (in the [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows))) until the background work is finished.

Comment: It's not really well emphasised here but I think you're talking about a specific scenario of when the user tries to close the application, you want to wait until the background worker is completed before allowing it to finally exit, correct?

Comment: @Damien: Keeping the UI responsive is related to standard application usage, not to the closing operation in question.

Comment: @abenci first of all, BGW has a `RunWorkerCompleted` event. Second `DoEvents()` isn't needed at all since the BGW *doesn't* run on the UI thread. Fubakkt it's obsolete since 2012. Anything it does can be done in an easier way using async/await, Task.Run etc. Composing multiple asynchronous operations is something that the BGW *can't* do at all. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @abenci what are you really trying to do? Why not run the long running/async operation with a simple `await Task.Run(someMethod);` ?

Comment: @abenci finally, hiding the applications window has nothing at all to do with background processing. Just don't create a form. Even Winforms applications are *console* applications that perform some extra setup. Or *minimize* the form. Or close it and keep a tray notification icon

Comment: DoEvents() is a nasty hack to allow the RunWorkerCompleted event handler to run.  Never write code like this, re-entrancy bugs kill you dead.  All you need to do is Hide() your window, call Close() in your RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Comment: `DoEvents()` call is not relevant to the question, the code was copied from a Microsoft documentation sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `WaitHandle` to keep synchronization with the worker thread.

```
private ManualResetEvent _canExit = new ManualResetEvent(true);

private DoBackgroundWork()
{
    _canExit.Reset();
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(_canExit);
}

protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosed(e);

    // This foreground thread will keep the process alive but allow UI thread to end.
    new Thread(()=>
    {
        _canExit.WaitOne();
        _canExit.Dispose();
    }).Start();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ManualResetEvent mre = (ManualResetEvent )e.Argument;

    // do your work.

    mre.Set();
}
```

If you have multiple background thread to wait, manage a `WaitHanlde` collection and use `WaitHandle.WaitAll` to keep the process from exiting.

Comment: This is a good hint, but I think it should be `new ManualResetEvent(false)`

Comment: The initial state of the `ManualResetEvent` must be signaled, so the process can exit if background work never performed.

Comment: Ah ok, so you use `_canExit.Reset()` to set the state of the event to nonsignaled before starting the background work, good!

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in closing a form (what the user sees as the application) and closing the actual application. Assuming you currently have the background worker instance as a part of the form, you need to separate it into a different class. You can use a static class for a simple way to do this. Note this has a ManualResetEvent that will be fired when the worker is finished and an Action to override that the worker will invoke rather than specifying the DoWork event in the form.

```
public static class Background
{
    public static ManualResetEvent WorkerResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private static BackgroundWorker worker;
    public static BackgroundWorker Worker
    {
        get
        {
            if (worker == null)
            {
                worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
            }
            return worker;
        }
    }

    private static void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        WorkerAction?.Invoke();
        WorkerResetEvent.Set();
    }

    public static Action WorkerAction;
}
```

Now this isn't part of the form, it can persist after the form is closed. You can then keep the application running after the form has closed in a similar loop to the one you have. The simplest way to handle this is to have a 'parent' form that is not displayed but calls your existing form.

```
public class ParentForm : Form
{
    private void ParentForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Visible = false;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
        new Form1().ShowDialog(); // execution waits until form is closed

        // now wait for worker to finish
        while (Background.Worker.IsBusy)
        {
            Background.ResetEvent.WaitOne(5000); // Waits 5 seconds for the event
        }
}
```

You'll need to call ParentForm instead of Form1 in the Program class:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new ParentForm());
}
```

And to initialise the worker in your form. This also waits for the worker while updating the display but should quit out of the loop when the form is closed where the above loop will take over waiting.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool closing;
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        closing = true;
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        Background.WorkerAction = () =>
        {
            // your saving logic here
        };
        Background.Worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        while (!closing && Background.Worker.IsBusy)
        {
            Background.WorkerResetEvent.WaitOne(500); // wait half a second at a time (up to you)

            // any logic to update progress bar or other progress indicator
            Refresh(); // Update the screen without costly DoEvents call
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you missed this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx  there is a runworkercompleted - which is triggered on completion, cancelled or exception

```
bgworker.RunWorkerCompleted += JobCompleted;

private void JobCompleted(
    object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // First, handle the case where an exception was thrown.
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
    }
    else if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Job cancelled");
    }
    else
    {
        do_next_stuff();
    }

}
```